# Comparing each number from two different arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, int

I really need some help please!

So basically I'm programming a little game calles MoreLess. The game will be composed with 3 different modes. Actually I'm stuck on the first mod called "challenger". For this mod I have laready created 2 methods . The first one which takes in consideration the user input (4 digit number between 0 and 9) and the second method (random generated 4 digit number). Now I need to compare these 2 values for each number. For each number I need to print something. If the number is bigger = '+', if smaller = '-' else '='.

```
public static int[] pProposition() {
    Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Veuillez saisir votre proposition à 4 chiffres entre 0 et 9");
    String saisi = clavier.nextLine();
    if (saisi.length() != 4 || saisi.replaceAll("\\D", "").length() != 4) {
        System.out.println("Vous avez saisi un nombre incorrect. Vous devez saisir un nombre de 4 chiffres entre 0 et 9" );
    }
    int[] proposition = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        proposition[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(saisi.charAt(i)));
    }
    return proposition;
}

public static int[] genNumHasard() {
    int[] combSecrete = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < combSecrete.length; i++) {
        combSecrete[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 0);
    }
    return combSecrete;
}

public static int[] joueUnTour () {
    int valeurComparaison = PlusOuMoins.pProposition().compare
    if (PlusOuMoins.pProposition() > PlusOuMoins.genNumHasard()) ;
    {

    }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Why do you use array to store separate digits, it will be easy if you store all 4 digits in a single int variable.

Comment: You have posted a lot (or all) of your code and you say that you are stack. You need to tell as specifically on what you are stack, what you have tried and what you need help on. Otherwise, we do not know what to help you with.

Comment: You would do well to start by storing your two arrays in two local variables of type `int[]`.  Then you can use a **loop** to step through one of the arrays and compare _each item_ of that array against the _corresponding item_ of the other array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clearly,here is what you want.

```
 public static void compareNums(){

   int [] firstArr = pProposition();
   int [] secondArr = genNumHasard();

   for(int i=0;i<firstArr.length;i++){//Assuming array lenghts are same

       if(firstArr[i]>secondArr[i])
          System.out.println("For "+i+"th number result is"+" +");
       else if(firstArr[i]<secondArr[i])
          System.out.println("For "+i+"th number result is"+" -");
       else
          System.out.println("For "+i+"th number result is"+" =");
   }

}
```

Comment: The idea is there but the results are not accurate . I'm not getting the exact return. If I input a random 4 digit number let's say 4562 and the random number is 8563 i will not get +(4 < 8) , = (5 ==5) , = (6==6) , + (2<3) etc...

Comment: The random value array changes after the keyboard input

Answer (score 0):

you just need to compare two array,if you can use Java 8 and Guava,try this code:

```
public static void compareArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    Streams.zip(Arrays.stream(arr1).boxed(), Arrays.stream(arr2).boxed()
            , (integer, integer2) -> integer - integer2 == 0 ? "=" : integer - integer2 > 0 ? "+" : "-")
            .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}
```